# XSLT insert subset of source

Tags: xslt

I am having trouble with a XSLT: Need to simply copy-of the children of a source node into the result structure.

```
<source>
  <sub1>
    <id>val</id>
    <keynode><name>Name1</name><value>Value1</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name2</name><value>Value2</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name3</name><value>Value3</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name4</name><value>Value4</value></keynode>
  </sub1>
</source>
```

I need to simply transfer the contents of sub1 to new structure:

```
<newstruct>
  <newsub1>
    <id>val</id>
    <keynode><name>Name1</name><value>Value1</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name2</name><value>Value2</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name3</name><value>Value3</value></keynode>
    <keynode><name>Name4</name><value>Value4</value></keynode>
  </newsub1>
</newstruct>
```

I have simplified things a bit, but the issue is the need to copy (inclusive of namespaces, attributes, children, etc- deep copy) the children specified by an XPath. In this example from root: /source/sub1/*

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out right after post.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/source/sub1/*"/>
```